# Where can I find the most recent snapshot of gnome-shell?

Tags: 10.10, gnome

I would love to try out the latest gnome-shell from git but it is having difficulty compiling on my machine. Not to mention, it's an extremely time-consuming process with terse error messages, so it's been hours of trial-and-error so far. I even tried it on a natty setup but it didn't work. The one from the repos works great, but it's fairly outdated from what I understand. Are there any charitable devs out there that want to contribute a deb or PPA for those of us who would like to try it out?

Comment: Possibly related instructions question on compiling g-s: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5634/compiling-latest-gnome-shell

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be a PPA of git snapshots for 10.10, unfortunately. *However*, it is actually rather simple to build yourself: upstream (gnome-shell developers) have provided [an easy-to-follow guide telling you how to do this](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell#Building). You could give that a go.

Answer (score 2):

There's an even easier tutorial on building it [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-gnome-shell-from-git-in-ubuntu.html) that also gives you solutions for common problems you may encounter.

Answer (score 0):

PPA with testing version of gnome-shell is available, but only for Natty -- https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing

You can try to use it in Maverick (but it probably won't work).